# How to run QTP scripts from Jenkins installed on linux?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have Jenkins on linux and i want to run QTP scripts (windows shell command) through the jenkins.

Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

**1. Install `HP Application Automation Tools` plugin in Jenkins**
*Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Install*

a)  Configure your ALM server, *Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Application Lifecycle Management*

**2. Add a jenkins agent in a windows machine - Machine 1**
*You can use JNLP to launch slave agent*

**3. Add Machine 1 as a new node in Jenkins master** 
*Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> New Node* When creating give a *meaning label for the node, which will be later used in the Jenkins job.*

**4. Create a new Jenkins job, Plug in all the mandatory values, select `Restrict where this project can be run` and enter the label created in step 3**

**5. In the build step select `Execute HP functional tests from HP ALM`** *Enter the username, password, domain, project and test set details*